# build runner package in my flutter app for JSON serialization not working

Tags: flutter

I'm using build_runner package in my flutter app for JSON serialization. I've correctly installed it in `pubspec.yaml` file under `dev dependencies`. but when I try to use `flutter pub run build_runner build` it releases the following.

```
    C:\Users\MoBix\Music\islamic_social_media>flutter pub run build_runner build
Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Unable to generate package graph, no `C:\Users\MoBix\Music\islamic_social_media\.dart_tool\flutter_gen\pubspec.yaml` found.
#0      _pubspecForPath (package:build_runner_core/src/package_graph/package_graph.dart:232:5)
#1      _parsePackageDependencies (package:build_runner_core/src/package_graph/package_graph.dart:206:21)
#2      PackageGraph.forPath (package:build_runner_core/src/package_graph/package_graph.dart:101:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      main (file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/build_runner-2.1.5/bin/build_runner.dart:27:30)
<asynchronous suspension>
pub finished with exit code 255
```

my `pubspec.yaml`

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
  flutter_app_name: ^0.1.1
  build_runner:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

my `flutter doctor -v`

```
C:\Users\MoBix>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1348], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.5.3 at C:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 18116933e7 (6 weeks ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
    • Engine revision d3ea636dc5
    • Dart version 2.14.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\MoBix\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-Sv2, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.45
    • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 94.0.992.50

• No issues found!
```

What is the fix for this?

Comment: Did you run 'flutter clean' and 'flutter pub get' afterwards, before you run the build_runner command? Also, do you happen to have 'generate: true' in your pubspec? If so, and if it's not needed, try removing it

Comment: thanks @dumazy I removed generate:true and it worked

Comment: Great :) I've added it as an answer in case others might run into the same issue

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's interesting that it points to `.dart_tool/flutter_gen/pubspec.yaml`. This [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/2835) mentions this problem when `generate: true` is set in the `pubspec.yaml`.

If you don't need that, try removing it. Also, a `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` might be necessary.

Comment: what does generate: true do?

Comment: flutter packages pub get, worked for me

Comment: `flutter clean` was enough for me 

Comment: @JZAU Please refer [Flutter and the pubspec file](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/pubspec) and [Internationalizing Flutter apps](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#adding-your-own-localized-messages) regarding generate flag.

Comment: `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 7):

In my case this was happening to me trying to generate the code for testing using mockito and the annotation:

```dart
@GenerateMocks([ClassToMock])
```

The errorappear trying to do `flutter pub run build_runner build`  and the `<...>/.dart_tool/flutter_gen/` path doesn't exist.

The solution was creating an empty `.dart_tool/flutter_gen/pubspec.yaml` file:

```bash
mkdir .dart_tool/flutter_gen && touch .dart_tool/flutter_gen/pubspec.yaml
```

And fullify it with (as pointed [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/2835#issuecomment-920640502)):

```yaml
name: test
description: A new Flutter application.
version: 1.0.0

dependencies:

dev_dependencies:
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add `flutter_gen` to `dev_dependencies` to override the embedded one.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty popular answer on GitHub by [Ali Yazdi](https://github.com/aliyazdi75) where they suggest to remove the `l10n.yaml` file, and then run `flutter clean` and then run `flutter packages pub get`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exception but my solution was strange:

I generated localization code and files first with:

```
flutter gen-l10n
```

and then generating others with:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

worked seamlessly.